# Connecting Database to Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile.I have a question which is bothering me quite a bit, How do I pull up data from the database . Is Javascript used for that ?

Comment: This is a very broad question. You probably want to run your database on a server so start by picking a database and a server-side language, like MongoDb and Javascript on node.js or MySql and PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GWT(Google web Toolkit) with JQueryMobile wrapper class
Refer the links
https://github.com/jqm4gwt/jqm4gwt
Examples:
[jqm4gwt.appspot.com](http://jqm4gwt.appspot.com)

Comment: Links may not be considered as answers.